# Another way to say "Does not matter" in formal reports

Tags: synonyms, writing

The phrase "does not matter" sounds rather informal to me. I'm writing a formal report and would appreciate alternative suggestions.

For example:

"The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is heavy precipitation from time to time. However, this does not matter because most residents have a habit of working from home."

Comment: '... this is immaterial' is about as close as it gets in meaning, and as far away as it gets in register.

Comment: What does "in register" mean? Are you making a reference to music theory?

Comment: [**register**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/register) *noun*: 3. Linguistics A variety of a language or a level of usage, as determined by degree of formality and choice of vocabulary, pronunciation, and syntax, according to the communicative purpose, social context, and social status of the user. Oxford Dictionaries.com

Comment: Thanks Little Eva. So Edwin Ashworth was saying "this is immaterial" is the best candidate in terms of what I'm looking for.

Comment: In terms of its meaning and register, yes.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions - it is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, _does not matter_ sounds informal to OP but I wonder if it really is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using "this is irrelevant".

> The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is heavy precipitation from time to time. However, this *is irrelevant* because most residents have a habit of working from home.

The definition of "[irrelevant](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/irrelevant)":

> not useful or not relating to a particular situation, and therefore not important
>   *The defendant's lawyer argued that his past offenses were irrelevant to this case.*

Comment: I would avoid irrelevant, it can sound rude.

Answer (score 5):

inconsequential- adjective
The definition of inconsequential is something unimportant or something that doesn't matter.

Comment: The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is heavy precipitation from time to time. However, this is inconsequential because most residents have a habit of working from home.

Comment: Best answer! From a lowly Car-salesman! lmao

Comment: Hello again! You should edit your answer to include the sample sentence. Comments on this website have a habit of disappearing without any warning. Answers tend to be more permanent, unless they are gibberish or  they don't answer the question, in which case they can be deleted by the community or the mods.

Answer (score 2):

"The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is heavy precipitation from time to time. However, this is of **minor significance/minor importance** because most residents have a habit of working from home."

You could also say **unimportant**

Answer (score 1):

I would say in what way it doesn't matter, for example:

> The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is
>   heavy precipitation from time to time; this doesn't make the
>   residents' living conditions poorer, because most of them have a habit
>   of working from home.

Why? Because if saw a formal report and it contained a sentence along the lines of "xyz, but this doesn't matter" I'd be inclined to wonder why they bothered mentioning it :)

This is perhaps in part due to my pedantry, and in part due to advancing age and my increasing appreciation for things being spelt out to me.

Comment: But if you are really pedantic, *enjoy favorable living conditions* tells me nothing- what's favorable to one may be unfavorable (or unimportant)  to another.

Comment: I agree with both of you. These ideas are elaborated upon in the report.

Comment: You make a cogent point, Karasinsky.

Answer (score 1):

While the OP seeks a synonym for “does not matter,” by the time I arrived on the scene @Catija had already submitted a perfectly apt response, after which, if the adjective “irrelevant” wasn’t acceptable, all that was required to find one that was, was a quick googling of the adjective and, *voila tout*!---unimportant, immaterial, inconsequential, insignificant, meaningless, trivial, of no matter or consequence, of little account, beside the point, neither here nor there, etc., etc., etc.---so, rather than pursuing that, I turned my attention to a different problem I saw with the OP (writing), one that I thought would have even more bearing on the quality of FreshAir’s final product.

The problem I saw was this:

**1**. The first sentence claims that the residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions.

**2**. The second sentence significantly qualifies the first sentence, yet must be accounted for.

**3**. The third sentence seeks to diminish the import of the second sentence (which brings us back to the gist of the OP) by seeking a formal stand-in for “this does not matter,” i.e., the periodically heavy precipitation.

Although each sentence of this paragraph is undoubtedly true and valid, each sentence also recedes from the import of the preceding sentence.

Aside from completely reconstructing the paragraph, I believe the solution to the problem lies in a slight rewording of the second sentence and its merger with the third, while avoiding the use of “this does not matter,” or *any* of its synonyms.

The heavy precipitation that occurs from time to time *does* matter. It matters to the validity of the first sentence, it matters to the residents of City X, and it will matter to those who read the report.

Though it can probably be improved, here’s an example of the rewording and merger I spoke of:

"The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. Due to the occasional heavy precipitation most residents have adopted the habit of working from home."

I apologize if my first answer was indecipherable, and I surely hope this is better.

Comment: I disagree... In this case it's definitely worth noting that there's often heavy rainfall (say as information for someone who is considering moving to the area or visiting it) but it is good information to point out that it doesn't necessarily impact a lot of people because they work from home.

Comment: @Catija - you misunderstood me. I didn't suggest omitting mention of  the rainfall, I suggested not using terms equivalent to "this does not matter," (i.e., irrelevant, unimportant, inconsequential, et.) since it matters enough to the author to include the fact in the first place. I recommended other ways around the problem.

Comment: You literally say "issues that don't matter have no place in your report". If what you say in your comment is what you **mean**, then you should change your answer.

Comment: Than you for taking the time to consider my answer, rather than rejecting it out of hand, Fresh Air. I hope it was of some help. :-)

Comment: Here's another good answer that you'd probably appreciate that never got much play, @Tushar Rag.

Answer (score 1):

The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is heavy precipitation from time to time, but this detail is negligible due to residents' widespead habit of working from home.

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally necroing this post to add my GED level input.

Original post;

The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions. There is heavy precipitation from time to time. However, this does not matter because most residents have a habit of working from home.

What I would have wrote;

The residents of City X enjoy favorable living conditions, even with heavy precipitation from time to time, because most residents have a habit of working from home."

Assuming this was taken out of context, I may have worded it differently, if I had read the whole piece. Furthermore,  I wouldn't word the beginning or ending like the original either, but I digress.